# Reputation of 1 Year Master's in Comp. Sc. in the UK

Tags: masters, united-kingdom, germany

I'm currently studying for my Bachelor's degree in Computer Science in Germany.
I've noticed that UK Master's programs, even at such prestigious universities as Oxford or Edinburgh, only offer 1 year Master's programs for full time study.
In Germany, on the other hand, Master's are usually 2 years / 4 semesters.

I was wondering how this is perceived in academia. Say for a professor in the US offering a PhD position, would he expect people from the German two-year program to be better at their subject? (Assuming grades are similar).

Comment: Are you looking at taught masters courses, or research ones?

Comment: Tendency is towards a taught one, but I'm also open to a research one.

Comment: In general, a student who has completed an MS thesis (as opposed to doing a course-work only MS) will be better prepared for PhD research.  Furthermore, the thesis itself is something that a potential PhD advisor can evaluate as evidence of the student's research ability.  MS degrees with course-work only are typically "terminal" master's degrees designed to prepare students for careers in industry rather than further study at the PhD level.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I did assume that all MS programs would require writing a thesis. At least for the one-year program in Edinburgh, these seems to be the case: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/student-services/teaching-organisation/taught-course-information/year-guides/taught-postgraduate-year-guide/degree-requirements