# Are 1-year MSc programmes in the UK recognised the same as typical European 2-year programmes

Tags: masters, computer-science, united-kingdom, switzerland

I come from a BSc in Computer Science background, and am looking into enrolling into a Masters programme.

I am considering some programmes in the UK (e.g. University of Edinburgh) and comparing them to the MSc programmes in Europe (e.g. at EPFL Switzerland). I have noticed a number of UK MSc programmes are only 1 year long, while in contrast, the European ones typically take two years (and in case of EPFL, may take some time more, due to the programme difficulty).

My question is: **are 1-year UK programmes and 2-year European ones  recognized as being (approximately) equal value and at the same level of education** (Europe-wide or world-wide), **when looking for entry-level industry positions**? Of course there are other factors like the institution reputation and quality involved, but this is assuming institutions of similar quality.

I created this post to get reviews from students who had to take a similar decision and studied in one or both of those universities.

Looking further [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/31504/4249) question seems to be looking for similar information, but has not been answered.

Comment: Which is better known UoE or EPFL? That depends how you define _better known_. We can say they are both well-ranked institutions: https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/university-edinburgh and https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/ecole-polytechnique-federale-de-lausanne

Comment: When I was applying to a CS PhD program in the US, I had no recognition problems with my London University CS master's degree. I took 2.5 years doing it part time, but full time it was a one year program.

Comment: Similarly, whether Edinburgh's MSc is _truly recognized_ depends on how you define the phrase. But, that doesn't seem particularly relevant. The main distinction between a one- and two-year MSc seems obvious: The latter has the possibility of delivering at least twice the material.

Comment: Degrees from reputable universities (and both of these are) are generally recognized at face value. Think of them as different, rather than one being superior. There is more to consider than the elapsed time.

Comment: @ArnoldMurie I know that my edit substantially changed your question, but I think this is something we could answer under the scope of this site. Making specific decisions or comparisons for you (specific Uni of X vs. Institute of Y; cost-of-living; tuition; job prospects after a specific programme at Uni X in country X) are unfortunately all out-of-scope here. Feel free to revert the edit if you do not feels the question reflects what you want to know any more, but if editing yourself, please try to follow the above guidelines.

Comment: @Buffy I think your comment (perhaps expanded a little) could be a good answer to the rephrased question. That is; if the community and the author both agree that the question is now in-scope.

Comment: @penelope Your edit is excellent, but I don't think you've reached the "right" question. _would a diploma from both 1-year UK programmes and 2-year European ones be recognized as of (approximately) equal value and as a same level of education_? The answer to both is _no_, a 1-year programme is not equal to a 2-year programme, the latter can deliver a higher level of education.

Comment: @user2768 I think we'll have to see if the OP agrees with the spirit of the question - as I think it could still be a "right" question even if the answer is "no" as you suggest. If you think the question can be formulated better, please go ahead, but I have a feeling this is what the OP was asking. (And I also personally think the answer is "yes": a 2-year programme from the same rank Uni could teach you more than a 1-year one, but you'll still be considered as having finished a Masters programme when applying for jobs or for a PhD, but let's agree on the question first please).

Comment: _recognized as of (approximately) equal value_ I must ask, equal value in what sense? Academic career or Industry career?

Comment: @scaaahu Well, I couldn't really deduct that from the original question, so I just assumed (the OP is enrolling into MSc after all) that he is considering both options and phrased it in the edit as "both for further continuing my studies afterwards or when looking for entry-level industry positions". OP is not responding to the edit, so perhaps if you see how it could be further clarified you could try to edit it yourself?

Comment: Thanks for trying to reformulate my question. I'm not interested in doing a PhD so it would be for an industry career.

Comment: @ArnoldMurie Why not edit the question to make that clear?

Comment: _I created this post to get reviews from students who had to take a similar decision and studied in one or both of those universities._ I think that's off topic?